# How to access an element in an object Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

The following is the object

```
Object {
  "index": 0,
  "item": Object {
    "-1509965540253": "Hey Blade Runner!!",
    "fName": "Gaston Day Public School",
    "fromName": "Gaston Day Public School",
    "message": "HEy ! Full metal jacket !",
    "time": -1509967894467,
  },
  "separators": Object {
    "highlight": [Function highlight],
    "unhighlight": [Function unhighlight],
    "updateProps": [Function updateProps],
  },
}
```

I want to access `fromName` in the following function

```
renderInboxList= (item) =>{
 console.log("FromName",item.fromName);
  return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={item.fromId} onPress={() => {console.log("TOmoving to chat thread");navigate('ChatThread', { fromId: `${l.fromId}` });}}>
              <ListItem
                key={item.fromId}
                leftIcon={{ name: 'user-circle-o', type: 'font-awesome', style: {color: 'blue'} }}
                title={item.fromName}
                titleStyle={{color: 'red'}}
                subtitle={item.message}
                rightTitle={item.time}
                rightTitleStyle={{color: 'green'}}

                />
                </TouchableOpacity>);
              }
```

The `item.fromName` gives me `undefined`.

Comment: If `item` is your variable name for the whole object then it would be `item.item.fromName`

Comment: Yes!... That was the issue. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
var fromName = item.item.fromName;
```